# podman resolv.conf is different from host

Tags: podman, resolv

The content of /etc/resolv.conf is different inside the container from what it is on the host. The "search" domains are missing in the resolv.conf inside the container resulting in failure of name resolution unless I use fully qualified domain name.

I know the existence of --dns-search option, but would like to know why and how resolv.conf is different from the host.

Host: Redhat 9
Podman image: Redhat 9 base image
Podman version: 4.2.0

**on the host:**

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
search abc.int admin.abc.int network.abc.int
nameserver 127.0.0.1
options timeout:1
options attempts:3

# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.1 (Plow)
```

**inside the container:**

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.123.45.67

# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.1 (Plow)
```

I expect the search domains to be present in the resolv.conf of the container too.
Any suggestions would help.